# Getting a round blur halo around a square button in order to place over an image

Tags: swift, uibutton, autolayout, uiblureffect

[image: Rough example of what I am trying to do]

I updated this with an image of what I am trying to achieve, its a blur on a image which adds a touch of shading and even white on white is visible.  I am basically working on putting buttons of various kinds on top of images and welcome's any and all assistance on best practices.  I know facebook does this in some way as an app example.

To summarize what I am trying to achieve.  I have an image that takes up the full screen and I would like to place a button on top of that image that does something like blur around it with padding so that it looks clean on top of the image.  My button is a heart png, red outline with clear inside, and is represented as a square because of the irregular shape.  I would like the heart to be on top of a circle that does something like blur the image so it can always be seen.

I found a number of similar solutions to this problem using UIBlurEffect but nothing that specifically addresses the "square image" and how I would control making the blur circle larger/smaller in terms of the padding around the square. I tinkered with creating a UIView that was transparent, placing a circle with a blur into there and then adding the button with their centers aligned but this seems like an incorrect approach and wasn't quite working.  I suspect that for people with expertise this is something where I just need to have the correct usage of the UIBlurEffect.

Comment: Can you please attach an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Let me work on an image in Adobe of what I am trying to achieve.  An app that does something similar is the iPhone phone app.  When you are on a call there are circular buttons for mute, keypad, speaker, add call, facetime, and contacts.  The button images are inside a circle.  In my ideal example my heart image would be inside that circle, the circle would be a blur effect, and I would be able to make the circle larger or smaller by adjusting an integer value or something.

Comment: I added an image.  Hopefully this helps clear up what I am trying to do?